# Python Как сложить значения одинаковых ключей в OrderedDict словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

как сложить значения одинаковых ключей в `OrderedDict` словаре?
например, чтобы при вводе:

```
4
a 5
b 7
c 3
a 5
```

значения одинаковых ключей сложились?

пока иду в этом направлении, но не понимаю как преобразовать value из str в int:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter, defaultdict

n = int(input('How Many N?:'))
order = OrderedDict(input('key and value: ').split() for _ in range(n))
order1 = defaultdict(int)

for key, value in order.items():
    order1[key] += int(value)

c = Counter()
for d in order1:
    c.update(d)
print(order1)
```

или

```
 from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

 n = int(input('How Many N?:'))
 order = OrderedDict(input('Product name and volume separate by a space: ').split() for _ in range(n))
 c = Counter()
 [c.update({k: int(v)}) for k,v in order]
 print(order)
```

Comment: а у вас правда получилось создать словарь или `OrderedDict` с __одинаковыми__ ключами?? Можете показать вывод команды: `print(order)` где мы увидели бы хотя бы два одинаковых ключа? Или вы хотите складывать вместо того чтобы записать дублируещее значение ключа?

Comment: print(order) выводил последнее значение, заданное для переменной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сложить все значения можно так:

```
order1 = {}
for key in order:
    try:
        order1[key] += int(order[key]) 
    except:
        order1[key] = int(order[key])
```

А красивый вывод можно сделать так:

```
for key, value in order1.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: тогда как сложить значения одинаковых ключей? мое решение, с учётом ваших уточнений выдаёт странные результаты. Например сейчас я создал словарь из 'a' 3 'a' 4 'b' 2 'b' 5 и он вместо a 7 b 7 вывел a 8 b 10

Comment: @MeinJunior исправлено